How to use multiple xticks/axis labels at different orientations to group together subgroups?
I have written a Python script (below) to produce a Matplotlib plot to display boxplot data grouped together by subgroups (season), groups (city), and different colors (year).
However, the group (city) labels are quite crude (achieved by including several spaces in the label text), and I am searching for a better way to achieve this. Currently, the city labels are not exactly centered within each group of seasons, and they do not scale if the size of the plot is changed.
Another feature I would like is for the season labels to be at a 45-degree offset while keeping the city text horizontal (as shown in the plot).
How can I achieve this in a better, more Pythonic way?
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# data_city_year = [[Spring], [Summer], [Fall], [Winter]]
data_a = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5], [7,2,5]] # NYC 2016
data_b = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []] # NYC 2017
data_c = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5], [7,2,5]] # Chi 2016
data_d = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []] # Chi 2017
data_e = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5], [7,2,5]] # Hou 2016
data_f = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []] # Hou 2017
data_g = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5], [7,2,5]] # LA 2016
data_h = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []] # LA 2017

def set_box_color(bp, color):
    plt.setp(bp['boxes'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['whiskers'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['caps'], color=color)
    plt.setp(bp['medians'], color=color)

plt.figure()

box_width = 0.6
space_year = 0.4
space_season = 2.0
space_city = 10

bpl = plt.boxplot(data_a, positions=np.array(range(len(data_a)))*space_season-space_year, sym='', widths=box_width)
bpr = plt.boxplot(data_b, positions=np.array(range(len(data_b)))*space_season+space_year, sym='', widths=box_width)
set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C')
set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')

bpl = plt.boxplot(data_c, positions=np.array(range(len(data_a)))*space_season-space_year+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
bpr = plt.boxplot(data_d, positions=np.array(range(len(data_b)))*space_season+space_year+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C')
set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')

bpl = plt.boxplot(data_e, positions=np.array(range(len(data_a)))*space_season-space_year+space_city+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
bpr = plt.boxplot(data_f, positions=np.array(range(len(data_b)))*space_season+space_year+space_city+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C')
set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')

bpl = plt.boxplot(data_c, positions=np.array(range(len(data_a)))*space_season-space_year+space_city+space_city+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
bpr = plt.boxplot(data_d, positions=np.array(range(len(data_b)))*space_season+space_year+space_city+space_city+space_city, sym='', widths=box_width)
set_box_color(bpl, '#D7191C')
set_box_color(bpr, '#2C7BB6')

# draw temporary red and blue lines and use them to create a legend
plt.plot([], c='#D7191C', label='2016')
plt.plot([], c='#2C7BB6', label='2017')
plt.legend(loc='upper center')

ticks = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
plt.xticks((0,2,4,6,10,12,14,16,20,22,24,26,30,32,34,36), ticks, rotation=45)
plt.plot()
plt.xlabel('New York                     Chicago                        Houston                      Los Angeles')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



Can you explain how to interpret the data_x lists? (I could go through the code and figure it out, but it might be easier if you explained it.) Have you considered using Pandas and Seaborn? I have a feeling it will be easier to get what you want that way.

Hi @jared, thanks for your help. I've changed the variable names and added a comment so that they are hopefully easier to understand. Each data_City_Year list represents a city in a particular year. Each list contains a list of seasons (spring, summer, fall, winter). I haven't come across any solution in Pandas/Seaborn/Matlab - is there anything in particular you could please recommend?

I believe this code addresses your issue. All the important changes are commented in the code. Feel free to remove and modify the pieces to understand what is happening. Basically I got rid off the hacky stuff with relevant matplotlib functions and applied good practices. Now you can also rescale your image without problem since the layout is not hardcoded any more.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Too much repetition for the sample (c, d, e, f, g, h are copies)
data_a = [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5], [7,2,5]]
data_b = [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []]

fig, ax = plt.subplots() # Use object syntax.

box_width = 0.6
space_year = 0.4
space_season = 2.0
space_city = 10

ticks_positions_array = np.array([])

# Avoid repetition with a for loop (mods only requiere changes in one place)
for indx, data_tuple in enumerate(
    [(data_a, data_b), (data_a, data_b), (data_a, data_b), (data_a, data_b)]
):

    left_boxplot = ax.boxplot(
        data_tuple[0],
        ## Use indx*space_city to add consistent spacing
        positions=np.array(range(len(data_tuple[0])))*space_season-space_year+indx*space_city,
        sym='',
        widths=box_width,
        ## Add coloring to the recipe instead of the set_box_color function,
        ## it is clearer, no need to hop to the function definition to know what is doing.
        patch_artist=False,
        boxprops=dict(color='#D7191C'),
        capprops=dict(color='#D7191C'),
        whiskerprops=dict(color='#D7191C'),
        medianprops=dict(color='#D7191C')
    )
    
    right_boxplot = ax.boxplot(
        data_tuple[1], 
        ## Use indx*space_city to add consistent spacing
        positions=np.array(range(len(data_tuple[1])))*space_season+space_year+indx*space_city,
        sym='',
        widths=box_width,
        patch_artist=False,
        ## Add coloring to the recipe instead of the set_box_color function,
        ## it is clearer, no need to hop to the function definition to know what is doing.
        boxprops=dict(color='#2C7BB6'),
        capprops=dict(color='#2C7BB6'),
        whiskerprops=dict(color='#2C7BB6'),
        medianprops=dict(color='#2C7BB6')
    )

    # Keep positions middlepoints to later add ticks:
    ticks_positions_array = np.concatenate(
        [
            ticks_positions_array,
            (np.array(range(len(data_tuple[0])))*space_season-space_year+indx*space_city +
            np.array(range(len(data_tuple[1])))*space_season+space_year+indx*space_city) /2.
        ]
    )

# No need to create empty plots to create a legend. Assign labels to the last to boxes
# of your previous for loop only. (The colors are already there)
ax.legend(
    handles=[left_boxplot["boxes"][0], right_boxplot["boxes"][0]],
    labels=['2016', '2017'],
    loc='upper center'
)

ax.set_xticks(
    ticks = ticks_positions_array, # No manual set, we already have the positions
    labels = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']*4, # You can multiply a list to reapeat its values.
    rotation=55
)

# City axis by duplicating x axis
ticks_positions_city = [ticks_positions_array[(i*4):(i+1)*4].sum()/4 for i in range (4)] # Avg of the 4 seasons.
ax_second_label = ax.twiny() # New second x axis that shares the same y-axis
ax_second_label.set_xlim(left=min(ticks_positions_array), right=max(ticks_positions_array)) # Fix the length of the axis to match the season one.
ax_second_label.set_xticks(
    ticks = ticks_positions_city, # No manual set, we already have the positions
    labels = ['New York', 'Chicago', 'Houston', 'Los Angeles']
)
ax_second_label.xaxis.set_ticks_position(position="bottom") # Move axis to bottom
ax_second_label.tick_params(
    axis='both',
    which='both',
    length=0, # Hide ticks by making them len=0
    pad=60 # Push down labels to avoid overlapping.
)



Use one axis per city. This allows you to use the x axis label / or the axis title to denote the city without using excess whitespace to align labels. You can remove the spines around an axis so that it appears as if there was only one plot.

For each city, a seaborn grouped boxplot gets you 90% of the way, and then it is just a matter of removing excess ink. This does require you to structure your data properly (look up the "tidy" format).



import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# convert to tabular data

data = [
    ("New York",    2016, [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5],   [7,2,5]]),
    ("New York",    2017, [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []]),
    ("Chicago",     2016, [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5],   [7,2,5]]),
    ("Chicago",     2017, [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []]),
    ("Houston",     2016, [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5],   [7,2,5]]),
    ("Houston",     2017, [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []]),
    ("Los Angeles", 2016, [[1,2,5], [5,7,2,2,5], [7,2,5],   [7,2,5]]),
    ("Los Angeles", 2017, [[6,4,2], [1,2,5,3,2], [2,3,5,1], []]),
]

tmp = []
for city, year, values in data:
    for subset, season in zip(values, ["spring", "summer", "autumn", "winter"]):
        tmp.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(city=city, year=year, season=season, value=subset)))
df = pd.concat(tmp, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# print(df)
#             city  year  season   value
# 0       New York  2016  spring     1.0
# 1       New York  2016  spring     2.0
# 2       New York  2016  spring     5.0
# 3       New York  2016  summer     5.0
# 4       New York  2016  summer     7.0
# ..           ...   ...     ...     ...
# 99   Los Angeles  2017  summer     2.0
# 100  Los Angeles  2017  autumn     2.0
# 101  Los Angeles  2017  autumn     3.0
# 102  Los Angeles  2017  autumn     5.0
# 103  Los Angeles  2017  autumn     1.0

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# plot

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4)
palette = {
    2016 : '#D7191C',
    2017 : '#2C7BB6',
}
for ax, city in zip(axes, df["city"].unique()):
    bp = sns.boxplot(data=df[df["city"]==city], x="season", y="value", hue="year", palette=palette, ax=ax)
    ax.set_xlabel(city)

# rotate x-tick labels
for ax in axes:
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(rotation=45)

# remove legends apart from last axis
for ax in axes[:-1]:
    ax.legend([], [], frameon=False)

# despine, remove y-ticks & y-label on all but the first axis
sns.despine(ax=axes[0], trim=True, offset=10)
for ax in axes[1:]:
    sns.despine(ax=ax, left=True, trim=True, offset=10)
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_ylabel('')

# match y-ranges
ymin, ymax = df["value"].min(), df["value"].max()
delta = (ymax - ymin) * 0.1
for ax in axes:
    ax.set_ylim(ymin-delta, ymax+delta)

# decrease space between axes; make more room for x-labels
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.05, bottom=0.2)

plt.show()


